# Semi-colon instead of Commas Power Apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have the same issue reported here :
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/Commas-in-formulas-not-semicolons/idi-p/241087

Commas do not work in Power Apps. Instead, I replace comma by the semi-colon. Problem is, I do not know what to use to replace the semi-colon.

Can someone help ?[image: Colon]

Answer (score 1):

In order to replace a semi-colon, we use 2 semi-colons

[image]

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/semicolon-as-separator-for-multiple-commands-in-OnSelect/td-p/510647

Answer (score 1):

Based on your region, you need to use either ; or ,.

For your issue use two semicolons (;;).

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are right.   In your region, use 2 semicolons.

Here's the link to the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/global#formula-separators-and-chaining-operator